# How to change value of /Rotate of a PDF page , without actually rotating Page Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I have pdf created with /Rotate page as -90 , when i add watermark , it is automatically rotating page and adding watermark at wrong location. I am looking to modify /Rotate value to 0 , without actually rotating the page. That is hard changing the metadata of pdf in Python.

Any idea if this can be achieved.

Tried pypdf2 , is there any other libraries

Comment: Try package PyMuPDF! Join the public [Discord](https://discord.gg/BZ9SF2FR) channel to connect with us.

Comment: You can preprocess the file with `cpdf -upright in.pdf -o out.pdf`. Or, as a python library: https://pypi.org/project/pycpdflib/

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf